# CSS railstutorial

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm following Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial and having some trouble getting my layout to match his, even though the code looks to be exactly the same.

Three things...

The Gravatar in the h1 in the show.html.erb is too small.

The user.name in the h1 in the show.html.erb is on two separate lines and too big.

Lastly, the debug box in the application.html.erb at the bottom of the page doesn't seem to clear the footer. Instead of being 45px below the footer it is smack bam on top.

custom.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";

/* mixins, variables, etc. */

$grayMediumLight: #eaeaea;

@mixin box_sizing {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* universal */

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

section {
  overflow: auto;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.center h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* typography */

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  line-height: 1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: $grayLight;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}

/* header */

#logo {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
}

#logo:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* footer */

footer {
  margin-top: 45px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid $grayMediumLight;
  color: $grayLight;
  a {
    color: $gray;
    &:hover {
      color: $grayDarker;
    }
  }
  small {
    float: left;
  }
  ul {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    li {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
  }


/* miscellaneous */

.debug_dump {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 45px;
  @include box_sizing;
}

/* sidebar */

aside {
  section {
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid $grayLighter;
    &:first-child {
      border: 0;
      padding-top: 0;
    }
    span {
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
      line-height: 1;
    }
    h1 {
      font-size: 1.4 em;
      text-align: left;
      letter-spacing: -1px;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
  }
}

.gravatar {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
}
```

show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
    <aside class="span4">
        <section>
            <h1>
                <%= gravatar_for @user %> 
                <%= @user.name %>
            </h1>
        </section>
    </aside>
</div>
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all",
                                           "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.5'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
  # The following optional lines are part of the advanced setup.
  # gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'
  # gem 'spork-rails', '4.0.0'
  # gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'
  # gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.4.0', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', github: 'bmabey/database_cleaner'

  # Uncomment this line on OS X.
  # gem 'growl', '1.0.3'

  # Uncomment these lines on Linux.
  # gem 'libnotify', '0.8.0'

  # Uncomment these lines on Windows.
  # gem 'rb-notifu', '0.0.4'
  # gem 'wdm', '0.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

This is the tutorials page
[image: Tutorials page]

This is mine, you can see the gravatar, h1 and debug box are considerably off.
[image: My page]

Comment: different browsers can cause slightly different displays like this... how far off target is it?

Comment: I checked firefox, chrome and ie and they all have the issue. It's far off enough that it has to be fixed.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the details of the tutorial... are you comparing your html page with an actual working html page example or with an image?

Comment: There you go. Now you're 10 :)

Comment: I hope that edit clears it up, cheers

Comment: Rather than screenshots, it's really helpful to put this sort of thing up on http://cssdesk.com/ or http://jsfiddle.net/ as they let people play with the css and test fixes out.  Often in the process of putting it up there you'll figure out the problem (when it turns out to be from a different stylesheet that you didn't think about for example)

Comment: Can jsfiddle and cssdesk work with all the other things like bootstrap and sass?

Comment: I think it's my class styling in the CSS file not working. I manually add the same styles in inspect element in a browser and it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You've failed to close the footer element in your CSS, looks like the closing } is at the end of the css file, this will prevent the css under this working properly:

```
footer {
  margin-top: 45px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid $grayMediumLight;
  color: $grayLight;
  a {
    color: $gray;
    &:hover {
      color: $grayDarker;
    }
  }
  small {
    float: left;
  }
  ul {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    li {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
  }
} ----!!! Missing!

.gravatar {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
} ----!!! Extra }!!
```