# Spacing/CSS Issue? - The Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

My issue with this tutorial is that my sign up form seems to be displayed in one single line. (Look at the form lines and also the debug box at the bottom). The font style is different in comparison to my site. (The bolded text on the original compared to mine.)

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

This is what its suppose to look like:
[image: What it is suppose to be]
But I have this:
[image]

Here is my CSS code:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

/* mixins, variables, etc. */

  $gray-medium-light: #eaeaea;

  @mixin box_sizing {
    -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing:         border-box;
  }

/* universal */

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

section {
  overflow: auto;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  h1 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}

/* typography */

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  line-height: 1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: $gray-light;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}


/* header */

#logo {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  &:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

/* footer */

footer {
  margin-top: 45px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid $gray-medium-light;
  color: $gray-light;
  a {
    color: $gray;
    &:hover {
      color: $gray-darker;
    }
  }
  small {
    float: left;
  }
  ul {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    li {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 15px;
    }
  }

  /* miscellaneous */

  .debug_dump {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 45px;
    @include box_sizing;
  }

  /* sidebar */

aside {
  section.user_info {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  section {
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
    &:first-child {
      border: 0;
      padding-top: 0;
    }
    span {
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
      line-height: 1;
    }
    h1 {
      font-size: 1.4em;
      text-align: left;
      letter-spacing: -1px;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
  }
}

.gravatar {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.gravatar_edit {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

/* forms */

input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  @include box_sizing;
}

input {
  height: auto !important;
}

/*END*/

}
```

View code for signup:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you need to see more files here they are here at Github:
https://github.com/jackytai/sample_app_rails/tree/sign-up

Source:
https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up#cha-sign_up

Comment: First question: Do you have any CSS errors showing up in your browser's console? Second question: Are you sure you're emitting elements in the same DOM structure as the original example? Can you inspect the original and see what rules are applied to those elements?

Comment: Using this site http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator. I validated my CSS custom and no issue. Not sure how to check the DOM structure you are talking about but when I use chrome inspector I see that the main container captures this div.

Comment: Maybe this is what you mean... I tried to disable the styles/elements in my chrome inspector one by one and see if there is an effect or something that is out of the ordinary but it did not seem to change my results either.

Comment: If there's a difference in style it's usually that different rules are being applied, so you'll have to track down why that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

My Footer CSS was not closed properly.

Thanks everyone

Source:
[CSS railstutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24054733/css-railstutorial)